# Need to convert any timezone to GMT time zone in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-package

Query condition is like below:

```
creation_date >=last_success_run_date
```

here creation date is coming like sometime PDT(Pacific Daylight Time) or sometime PST (Pacific Standard Time) format.

and last_success_run_date is always GMT format.

So, I want to know if is there any oracle function  available which will convert any timezone format to GMT timezone format.

Answer (score 0):

use `new_time()` function is used to convert a date from timezone1 to a date in timezone2.

```
NEW_TIME(date, timezone1, timezone2)

NEW_TIME(date, 'PDT', 'GMT')
```

Comment: we can't use new_time function here as we don't know time format will be PST or PDT

Comment: @send that in parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
FROM_TZ(creation_date, 'America/Los_Angeles') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

or

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(creation_date, 'America/Los_Angeles'))
```

If `creation_date` is a `DATE` rather than `TIMESTAMP` data type then you have to use `CAST(creation_date AS TIMESTAMP)` since `FROM_TZ` accepts only only `TIMESTAMP` datatypes as input value.